# how to return apointer to function in c

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

float Aco(char** c, int b, char* a)
    {
    ......
    }
    float Ma(char** c, int b, char* a)
    {
    ......
    }

```
float(*pointer)(char** c, int b, char* a);

?????Funk(int size)
{
 switch (startingLetter)
    {
    case 'a':
        return(&Aco);
        break;
    case 'b':
        return(&Ma);
        break;
    default:
        return NULL;
        break;
   }
}
```

If I want "Funk"  to return NULL or return the pointer to function Ma/Aco what do I need to write instead of `?????` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work?rq=1

Comment: When working with function pointers, it's easier if you define a `typedef` for it.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef double (*div_type)(int, int);

double div(int a, int b) {
    return ((double)a / (double)b);
}
div_type div_fun() {
    return (div);
    // or: return (NULL);
}

int main () {
    div_type fun_ptr = div_fun();
    if (fun_ptr != NULL) {
      printf("%f\n", fun_ptr(4, 2));
    } else {
      puts("Undefined");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

This will produce

```
% ./a.out
2.000000
```

Comment: and what about  NULL?

Comment: Just let div_fun return NULL. Obviously, this would produce a segfault in my example.

Answer (score 0):

*sans* typedefs:

```
float (*Funk(int size))(char** c, int b, char* a)
```

which reads as

```
        Funk                                         -- Funk
        Funk(        )                               -- is a function 
        Funk(int size)                               -- with parameter size
       *Funk(int size)                               -- returning a pointer
      (*Funk(int size))(                        )    -- to a function
      (*Funk(int size))(char **c, int b, char *a)    -- with parameters a,b, and c
float (*Funk(int size))(char **c, int b, char *a)    -- returning float
```

Note that you don't need the `&` when returning the functions; function expressions, like array expressions, "decay" to a pointer type.  So, you can just write:

```
case 'a':
    return Aco;
    break;
case 'b':
    return Ma;
    break;
default:
    return NULL;
    break;
```

Comment: thank you very very much